# How field operator $\Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r)$ transform under translation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, many-body

In many-body quantum theory, many literatures say that the Green's function $G(\mathbf r t, \mathbf r' t')$ can be written as functions of $\mathbf r-\mathbf r'$, and of course $t, t'$ when the system has translational symmetry. However, I was not able to find any formal proofs about that, and that made me try proving this.

Since the retarded Green's function is 
$$ G^R(\mathbf r t, \mathbf r' t')=-i\theta(t-t')<[\Psi(\mathbf r,t), \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r', t')]_+>,$$
it would be helpful to investigate how field operators transform under translation. Let $T_{\mathbf a}$ be a translation operator. It can be easily shown that 
$$ T_{\mathbf a}=\int \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r)\Psi(\mathbf r-\mathbf a) d^3\mathbf r$$
and also $$[T_{\mathbf a}^\dagger, \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r)]=\Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r - \mathbf a).$$ 
Then
$$T_{\mathbf a}^\dagger \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r)T_{\mathbf a}= \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r)+[T_{\mathbf a}^\dagger, \Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r)]T_a=\Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r)+\Psi^\dagger(\mathbf r-\mathbf a)T_a.$$
How can I proceed? Also, what is the precise statement for the Green's function to be a function of $\mathbf r -\mathbf r'$?

Comment: Your equations seem quite garbled and confused, where did you get them?

Comment: @knzhou I derived it myself, except for the retarded Green's function which is a definition.

Comment: Well, they certainly don't seem standard, so if you want a useful answer you should show how you derived them.